# return top-k closest distance from set X to set Y

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 2 sets of points, X and Y

The function pairwise_distances_argmin_min, found here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min.html

gives the top-1 distance from X to Y. However, for my application I am interested in top 2 or 3, and computing the full distance matrix between every elements from X to Y is too expensive.

What would be the best way to go about this?

thanks in advance

Comment: scipy cKDTree, maybe?

Comment: @Benjamin I will give it a shot, it looks like a good fit so far!

Answer (score 0):

working comment:

```
scipy cKDTree, maybe? – Benjamin 20 hours ago
```

The cKDTree constructed very quickly, and the query time is not too long for the top2 neighbors. With 10000 data-points of 32 dimensions.